# Linkage between two vertically and horizontally offset wheels

Tags: mechanical-engineering, torque, mechanisms, linkage

I'm trying to drive a wheel with a radius of 20cm that is 20cm above the motor and horizontally offset by 20cm from the motor, similar to the following:

[image]

I wonder what a good linkage might be for a setup like this. I've considered ball joints like below, but I don't think the allowable angle of the shaft is great enough:

[image]

I didn't want to go for expensive linkages like those with universal joints. Does anyone know what might be a good linkage for the wheels in this case? The torque required will be around 50Nm.

Any thought appreciated.

Comment: Could you help me understand what you mean by driving? And how were you planning to use the universal joint to drive? In mind driving in this context would mean to rotate about its axis each disk, however, I think you have something entirely else in mind.

Comment: why drive with linkages? do you not need continuous rotation?

Comment: As drawn the yellow connecting rod will hit the motor shaft after half a revolution. You need a better drawing

Comment: why not use a connecting rod like a steam engine with a standoff on the lower wheel so that you can just use a roller bearing?

Answer (score 0):

Put teeth on the circumference of the driver and then a gear on the shaft of the driven. Either they can mesh or use a chain or belt drive - depends on the torque/speed/power...

Of course if space is an issue consider a hydraulic link but is the speed ratio to be held constant or is there an acceptable tolerance.

Another option is to put gears on both shafts but below the two existing wheels.

Comment: Indeed, space is an issue and it'll have to be a linkage of some sort. Speed ratio and tolerance requirements are very low. Can I ask why a hydraulic link and not any link with ball joints? I'd rather not deal with hydraulics if I could.

Comment: @JohnM. Just gave you some ideas to consider, you already had ball joints on your list . I just thought that using a ball joint would need a mount above the surface on one and then due to the sweep nothing else on either surface ... but it’s your project, I just offered things you did not serm to be considering.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not certain 100% what you are trying to do, but from what I understand the wo solution you might want to consider are

- chains/pulleys : if the position of the shafts is fixed
- Schmidt linkage  ( [Video for operation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVt1tvD7rqk) ): if you want to move parallel one axis of rotation with the others.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should connect one of these swivel joint connectors, or similar, on the dependent wheel, and connect to the driving wheel's anchor point by a lever arm. https://www.dsti.com/landing/swivel-joints/

[image]